# spring file download using ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring

Hello i'm trying create an application allowing me host any kind of file.
In order to do it i'm exececuting following magic:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource 
    getFile(
            @PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) {
        System.out.println(fileName);
        String filePath = "./files/";
        return new FileSystemResource(new File(filePath+fileName)); 
    }
```

But this approach brings three unwanted problems:

1. Some random data is beeing appended to the file
2. The file gets opened in the browser window instead of beeing
           downloaded - i've tried to hack this using something like

   produces = "application/octet-stream"

   but it only resulted in 406 error.
3. The test.txt is beeing truncated into test, i found a walkaround in providing the app with test.txt/ as fileName but it looks a  bit messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)

> As with @RequestBody, Spring converts the returned object to a
>   response body by using an HttpMessageConverter

I think your problem is spring doesn't come with a HttpMessageConverter than can process FileSystemResource.

[A list of builtin HttpMessageConverter is available here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion). I suggest you try converting your response into byte array somehow, maybe it will pick ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter instead and help solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I used code like this to return image

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getImage(... HttpServletResponse response) {
      response.setContentType(image/png);
      (response.getOutputStream()).write(imageByteArray);
}
```

I think you have to define proper mime type and send your data to response.