# Spring Controller Not Returning File

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring Controller setup to return a file (particularly a .CSV) via an AJAX Request. Here's my call which is utilizing [YUI's](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/) framework which is making a standard XHR:

```
var downloadFile = Y.all('.downloadLink'); //traverses DOM for all downloadLink <a> tags
    downloadFile.on(
        'click',
        function(e){
            var fileName = e.currentTarget.attr('data-id');//retrieves file name
            Y.io.request(
            '/download/' + fileName, 
            {
                method: 'GET',
                on: {
                    success: function(e) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    failure: function(e) {
                        alert(e.type);
                    }
                 }
            });
    });
```

And here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/download/{fileName:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource download(@PathVariable String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(rootPath + tempDir + '/' + fileName);
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            logger.info(fileName + " downloaded");
            return new FileSystemResource(file); 
        } else {
            logger.error("Could not download: " + fileName + " does not exist on server");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error Downloading File");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

As suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers), I've tried forcing the download by modifying the method with

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
```

as well as including an **HttpeServletResponse** and setting the content type with

```
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
```

Without setting the MediaType, my request is successful and the `@ResponseBody` returns the contents of my file to the browser. However when I include the MediaType I receive a 406:

```
406 Not Acceptable: The resource identified by this request is only capable 
of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

I've searched the docs but I haven't found which "accepts" parameter I should be using to make this a valid request (if that alone would even resolve this issue). Any thoughts or suggested methods to retrieve my files? Cheers mates and Happy Easter

Comment: How are you making the request? You need to set `Accept` header in the request, to something like `Accept: application/octet-stream`

Comment: Good point, I'll include my AJAX request

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `Accept` header when you make a request. Never used YUI but try something like this

```
        Y.io.request(
        '/download/' + fileName, 
        {
            method: 'GET',
            on: {
                success: function(e) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                failure: function(e) {
                    alert(e.type);
                }
             }, 
            headers: {'Accept' : 'application/octet-stream'}
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @Predrag, `headers` is indeed a valid i.o.request attribute,however the same '406` error is returned with this set, though it makes perfect sense to do so

Comment: I believe the only strings accepted for the headers attribute are `*/*'`,
 `'text/html'`,
`'application/json'`, `'text/javascript'`,
`'text/plain'`, 
 `'application/xml'`, and `'text/xml'`. Source http://alloyui.com/api/files/alloy-ui_src_aui-io_js_aui-io-request.js.html#

Comment: I wouldn't expect any client framework to validate what you send in headers, as it is a very dynamic area. Anyway, try setting it to `*/*` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: After checking the actual Request Headers in the browser the request header is set to `*/*` by default. Strange because that's the wildcard for all data types if I'm not mistaken

Comment: After going through similar threads, it might not be client related at all. Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470413/4074715), could be a problem with message converters.