# Force Download CSV from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring

Follow up question from my [last issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461909/spring-controller-not-returning-file/29462448?noredirect=1#comment47096755_29462448) which has since been resolved.

I'm trying to download a file via a Spring `@Controller` by returning a `FileSystemResource`. I receive a valid HTTP 200 Response and can view all of the file's content in the browser, however I never receive the prompt to download the file. Here's my method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*", value = "/download/{fileName:.+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource download(@PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path + '/' + fileName);
    response.setContentLength((int)fileName.length());
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");//fileName);
    return  new FileSystemResource(file);
}
```

From the browser:

```
Response Headers
Content-Disposition | attachment; filename="my_data.CSV"
Content-Length  | 1712
Content-Type    | text/csv

Request Headers
Accept          | */*
Accept-Encoding | gzip, deflate
Accept-Language | en-US,en;q=0.5
```

Everything appears valid here; any idea why the actual file isn't getting returned?  Cheers

Comment: any updates ? even I am facing this same issue. everything seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

For download: i use:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

Note that your result "Content-Type    | text/csv" doesn't match what you set

Comment: I've used this but my Content Type remains the same. I'll debug and see when the type gets set because I'm not explicitly defining text/csv anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The minimum that worked for me is a combination of the code in the question, plus the octet-stream content type suggestion from @pdem. Everything else seems unnecessary:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/testcsv")
public @ResponseBody String getFile(HttpServletResponse response){
  String test = "test1, test2, test3";
  response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"test.csv\"");
  return test;
}
```